# Trying to merge 2 tables together to look like 1

Tags: html, css

I have a table that I broke out to two tables because I need to have the scrolling functionality only span the top table.  The bottom table is a textarea box.  What I need to do is make the bottom table blend right into the top table to looks as if its all 1 table while maintaining 2 tables. Maybe by modifying the borders?

```
<form id="commentForm" name="commentForm" action="" method="post">
<ctl:vertScroll height="300" headerStyleClass="data_table_scroll" bodyStyleClass="data_table_scroll" enabled="${user.scrollTables}">
<ctl:sortableTblHdrSetup topTotal="false" href="show.whatif_edit_entry?entryId=${entry.entryId}"/>
<table class="data_table vert_scroll_table" style="width:360px;">
    <tr>
    <th style="text-align: center;">User</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Date</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Comments</th> 
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="comments" items="${entry.comments}">
    <tr id="id${comments.id}">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${comments.auditable != null}">
        <td>
            ${comments.auditable.createdBy.lastName},   ${comments.auditable.createdBy.firstName}
      </td>


          <td title="<fmt:formatDate value="${comments.auditable.createdDate}" pattern="${date_time_pattern}" />"><span class="mouseover_text"><fmt:formatDate value="${comments.auditable.createdDate}" pattern="${date_time_pattern}" /></span>
          </td>

          </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
         <td  colspan="1">${lastName}, ${firstName}</td>
         <td title ="${comments.date}"><span class="mouseover_text">${comments.date}  </span></td>
    </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
    <td id="comments-${comments.id}"  style="width:400px;"><pre style="width: auto;">${comments.comment}</pre></td>

    </c:forEach>
    </tr> 

    <tr id="commentRow">    
    </tr>
    </table>
    </ctl:vertScroll>



    <c:if test="${lock.locked || form.entryId < 0 }">

    <%-- This is the row for adding a new comment. --%>           

    <table class="data_table vert_scroll_table" style="width:360px;">
        <td colspan="3">
        You have <strong><span id="commentsCounter">${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH'] - fn:length(commentForm.comment)}</span></strong> characters left.<br/>
            <textarea id="comment"   name="comment" rows="2" cols="125" style="width:400px;"

                onfocus="characterCounter('commentsCounter',${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)"
                 onkeydown="characterCounter('commentsCounter',${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)"
                 onkeyup="characterCounter('commentsCounter',${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)" ></textarea>

                    <a href="javascript:addComment();"><img src="../images/icon_add.gif" border="0" alt="Add"/></a>
        </td>



    </c:if>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try rethinking your markup. This would be much more suited:

```
<table>
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Comments</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     ...
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td>
           <textarea>...</textarea>
        </td>
     </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your code has some weird stuff in it `<c:forEach var="comments" items="${entry.comments}">`, I'm not gonna mess with it. But I will give the the answer in a nutshell. **Disclaimer:** This is how, I would do this, but probably there are better ways of doing things. Also, I'm using dotted borders for the demo.

**(1) Get the width's under control**

Lets make a global wrapper with set width.

```
<div style="width: 600px; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px dotted blue;">
    miley rocks!
</div>
```

**(2) Lets make an example table**

We are now making an example table with some random list. Also lets `width: 100%;` to the table, so it will match the global wrapper's width.

```
<table style="width: 100%; border: 1px dotted green;">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Hotness level</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Miley</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Selena</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>You</td>
        <td>-3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**(3) Now the second table**

Lets add the form table or aka. the second table..

```
<table style="width: 100%; border: 1px dotted blue;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <textarea name="my_textarea"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or why use `<table>`?

```
<div style="width: 100%; border: 1px dotted blue;">
    <textarea name="my_textarea"></textarea>
</div>
```

**(4) And now everything together**

All tables and containers together. This should result two containers with the same width.

```
<div style="width: 600px; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px dotted blue;">
    <table style="width: 100%; border: 1px dotted green;">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Hotness leve</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Miley</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Selena</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>You</td>
            <td>-3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div style="width: 100%; border: 1px dotted blue;">
        <textarea name="my_textarea"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Not sure how much this helps. But this is the general idea for that type of problem :)

Comment: Also you use tfoot and colspanning to use one single table for everything.